# Marionette CollectionView with one unique ItemView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, collectionview

Is there a way I can create a single unique view within a Marionette CollectionView? I mean something like this:

CollectionView

- StartView (this is the unique view)
- Regular ItemView
- Regular ItemView
- Regular ItemView
- etc.

By unique, I mean the "Start ItemView" must use a unique template, and not have the methods associated with the regular ItemViews.

Things I've tried:

- Just prepending the start view to the el of the CollectionView is not desirable, because my CollectionView's methods act on its child views.
- In the Marionette documentation, overriding buildItemView is suggested for this situation (I think?). I'm not sure how to override it. Just calling buildItemView doesnt work, because the StartView doesn't have an associated model or any options. Seems like I can't leave these args out, or it just returns undefined.
- I cant include the markup for a StartView in my CollectionView's template because... Marionette CollectionViews cant have a template.
- From the Marionette documentation, it doesn't seem like this fits the use case for the CompositeView. But maybe I'm wrong.

I'm probably missing something fairly obvious. Thanks in advance for the help.

edit: formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create 2 different views, 'StartView' and 'NormalView':

```
StartView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template:"#start-template'
});
NormalView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template:"#normal-template"
});
```

In your collection view, override getItemView and return your 'StartView' and 'NormalView'... something like this:

```
MyCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
   getItemView:function(item){
       if(item.get("ImTheFirst")===true)
          return StartView;
        else
          return NormalView;
    }
});
```

On the first item in your collection, add a property 'ImTheFirst' (for example) and set it to true.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for here is a [`CompositeView`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md).  A `CompositeView` is a mash-up between an `ItemView` and a `CollectionView`.  Essentially, the `CompositeView` itself would act as your `StartView`, and then you define an ItemView to act as your "Regular ItemView"'s.
Something like this:

```
RegularItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#regular-itemview-template"
});

CompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  itemView: RegularItemView,
  template: "#start-template"
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I have methods on the Composite View that should affect it's children (that means startView too).

- So the ItemViews have methods that the StartView does not.

- The Collection/Composite view has methods which should affect all children, including StartView.

Comment: I suspect you may misunderstand me - in my example, the `CompositeView` IS the `StartView`.  So whatever method you intended to be on the `StartView`, just put it in the `CompositeView` and call it with directly.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I have a method on the Composite/CollectionView that uses this.children.each() to determine the "current" child view. StartView should be one of the views that iterates though. Since StartView would not be considered a child of the CompositeView (since its just markup inserted through a template) I think that would cause issues.

Of course, there's probably a better way altogether of figuring out which view is at the top of the list of childViews at any given moment.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting.  Here's a thought - what if instead of a different View entirely for your StartView, you just had a flag you set on your ItemView, something like `this.active` (or put it on the model - `this.model.get("active")`, which would result in different markup being displayed in ItemView's template.  Then whenever you set a particular ItemView to be your "StartView", you simply set this flag on the ItemView, re-render that View, and retained a reference to this active View on your CompositeView (or CollectionView at this point).  Would that work?